How to create grouping and make it sticky in mobile screen using Tailwindcss with React?
I'm making a React table using Tailwind CSS without any UI library. I've implemented a sticky table header, and it's working well.
But when the screen is small, I want to make the first three columns stick on
the left side.
  <div className="overflow-auto max-h-full max-w-full">
      <table className="table relative">
        <thead className="sticky top-0 bg-slate-400">
          <tr className="text-center text-md">
            <th className="sticky left-0">Status</th>
            <th className="sticky left-0">JOB NUMBER</th>
            <th className="sticky left-0">CUSTOMER ID</th>
            {work.map((item, index) => (
              <th key={index}>{item}</th>
            ))}
            <th>DETAIL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <tr className="text-center">
                <td>{item.status}</td>
                <td>{item.jobNumber}</td>
                <td>{item.customerID}</td>

The above code is functional, but the columns are  in one location, as in this picture:

I'd like the first three columns to move together on the left side when the screen size is small. This way, users can still see those columns when they scroll horizontally.
